# Incorrect Acreage QGIS 2.6.0

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator

I have six polygons, all of (fairly) similar size. The first one is 8 acres, the others are obviously wrong with 120,000 acres, and 106,000 acres and so on. I am calculating with the field calculator, Geometry:

```
area* .000247
```

Is there something I should check? Is there another method I could use?

Comment: What projection do you have your data in?  Make sure it's in a local projected coordinate system like UTM or State Plane.

Comment: ... and make sure they are in meters and not feet.

Comment: Check your polygons are singleparts and check the geometry is valid.